# How to mock nil case of Rails.cache.fetch?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Consider the usage

```
Rails.cache.fetch("key", expires_in: 2.minutes) do
  do_something_to_get_value
end
```

I would like to mock with custom object

```
class FakeRedis
  def initialize() @data = {} end
  def clear() @data = {} end
  def write(key, val, *args) @data[key] = val end
  def read(key, *args) @data[key] end
  def expire(key, *args) @data.delete(key) end
  def fetch(key, *args) @data[key] end
end
```

For `nil` (`key` expires or never exists) case, how can I rewrite `fetch` to invoke code block afterwards and save to `@data`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def fetch(key, *args)
  return(@data[key]) if @data.kas_key?(key)
  @data[key] = yield if block_given?
end
```

`yield` is a method that will execute the block.

Answer (score 1):

It happens that ruby Hash has a nice `fetch` method that does almost the same, except that you have to explicitly set the key in the block:

```
class FakeRedis
  def fetch(key, *, &block)
    if block
      @data.fetch(key) { |h, k| h[k] = block.call }
    else
      @data[key]
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite it this way:

`def fetch(key, *args) @data[key] ||= yield if block_given? end`